# ListItem.get_id() return "-1" after adding value in custom list

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, client-object-model, csom

I am trying to add value in custom list of SharePoint using COM and Javascript.

Code work file but i can't see any item added in list. also i got id of recently added item is "-1"

This is my code.

```
function dooperation(retvalue){

                var ctx = new SP.ClientContext(url);
                var olist = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('userlist');

                var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
                this.oListItem = olist.addItem(itemCreateInfo);

                oListItem.set_item('Title',retvalue['Title'] );
                olist.update();
                ctx.load(olist);
                ctx.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
        }

function onQuerySucceeded() {

                alert('Item created: ' + oListItem.get_id());
        }

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

                alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
        }
```

Please Help..

Thanks in advance..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer updated code.

```
olist.update();
ctx.load(olist);
```

Is update to below

```
this.oListItem.update();
ctx.load(this.oListItem);
```

So the update function looks like below.

```
 function dooperation(retvalue){

                var ctx = new SP.ClientContext(url);
                var olist = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('userlist');

                var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
                this.oListItem = olist.addItem(itemCreateInfo);

                this.oListItem.set_item('Title',retvalue['Title'] );
                this.oListItem.update(); //Update list Item
                ctx.load(this.oListItem); //Load list Item
                ctx.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
        }

function onQuerySucceeded() {

                alert('Item created: ' + this.oListItem.get_id());
        }

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

                alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
        }
```

Comment: Thanks you so much buddy...
It works perfect. Can you please tell me why i have to **oListItem** ?

Comment: You have to get the information from server about the item you have created. That why you have to load it.

Comment: But still value of **Title** is not stored in list. and all values which i am passing are also not stored in list. only **Not Title** display in newly added item.

Comment: You need to check what value you have in `retvalue['Title']` , to verify the code just add some test data in title like `this.oListItem.set_item('Title','Test Title' );` . And see if new item created with title or not.

Comment: Thanks.. It work now. I am passing date in wrong format thats why i am getting error. Thanks for help..!!

Answer (score 0):

You should load your added item in your code before `executeQueryAync` call:

```
this.oListItem.set_item('Title',retvalue['Title'] );
this.oListItem.update();
ctx.load(this.oListItem);
```

Comment: Thanks ECM4D.. i want to ask you that where i have to put this code?
i have put this code just before **executeQueryAsync** but getting error..
Please Help..!!

Comment: I update the answer or look at the @Asad answer

Comment: Thanks you so much.. This also works... Can you please tell me exact reason what happen in my code?

Comment: But still value of **Title** is not stored in list. and all values which i am passing are also not stored in list. only **Not Title** display in newly added item.