# ListItem.get_id() return “-1” after adding value in custom list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

Hi i have referred to the below link as i have experiencing the same problem.
[ListItem.get_id() return “-1” after adding value in custom list 2](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/146921/listitem-get-id-return-1-after-adding-value-in-custom-list)

as i was facing similar issue. but it didnt solve my problem. Please see my code,
It adds the value but always returns -1 as the id.

```
   if (Description != null && Description.length > 0) {

            //alert(Description.length);
            // var obj = { Title: oListItem.get_item('Title'), ProductName: oListItem.get_item('Product_x0020_Name'), Price: oListItem.get_item('Price') };

            var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
            var oList1 = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Order');

            var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
            this.oListItem1 = oList1.addItem(itemCreateInfo);

            this.oListItem1.set_item('Description', Description);
            this.oListItem1.set_item('OrderID', str);
            this.oListItem1.set_item('Total', total);
            this.oListItem1.set_item('Comments', Comments);
            this.oListItem1.set_item('RFS_x0020_Number', rfsNumber);
            this.oListItem1.set_item('Branch', Branch);
            this.oListItem1.set_item('Division', Division);
            this.oListItem1.set_item('Target_x0020_Location', Targetlocation);
            this.oListItem1.update();
            document.getElementById('Text1').value = total;
            clientContext.load(this.oListItem1);
            clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded5), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed5));
            //alert(2);



            AddToOrderDetails();
        }

    }
    function onQuerySucceeded5() {

        alert('Item created: ' + oListItem1.get_id());
    }

    function onQueryFailed5(sender, args) {

        alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }
```

Comment: Can you try 'this. oListItem1. get_id()'  in the succeed method

Answer (score 0):

I have removed AddToOrderDetails(); from below executeQueryAsync and it worked for some reason. I am not sure why.